# how to pass php value from one file to another through java script

Tags: javascript, php, concrete5, concrete

I am working with Concrete-5 CMS, I have an issue in passing value form view to controller.In my application I am using following code for displaying employee role.

```
foreach($rd as $data){
    echo "<tr><td>".$data[role_name]."</td><td>".$data[role_description]."</td><td><a href=".$this->action('edit', $data['role_id']).">Edit</a></td><td>".$ih->button_js(t('Delete'), "deleteRole('".$data['role_id']."')", 'left', 'error')."</td></tr>";
}
<input type="hidden" name="rno" id="rno" />
```

script:

```
$delConfirmJS = t('Are you sure you want to remove this Role?'); ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function deleteRole(myvar) {
    var role = document.getElementById('rno');
    role.value = myvar;
    if (confirm('<?php echo $delConfirmJS ?>')) {
        $('#rolelist').submit();
        //location.href = "<?php echo $this->url('/role/add_role/', 'delete', 'myvar')?>";
    }
}
</script>
```

html code
I did edit operation by passing role_id through edit action. But, In case of delete i should ask for a conformation, so I use java script to conform it and call the href location and all.

But i don't know how to pass the role_id to script and pass to my controller. how to achieve this task?

thanks
Kumar

Comment: Put a class in HTML button that you are using for deleting role. Use jquery to catch click event and execute Sajith code in that...

Comment: I tried ajax code is not working to me.... thanks for your valuable suggestion

Comment: I update my code by using the hiden field and set value to hidden field rno and submit the form. but i have question 'location.href = "<?php echo $this->url('/role/add_role/', 'delete', 'myvar')?>";' this code will work or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass value to server using ajax calls.
See the following code. Here We use a confirm box to get user confirmation.

```
function deleteEmployee(empId){
   var confirm=confirm("Do you want to delete?");
   if (confirm)
   {
     var url = "path/to/delete.php";
     var data = "emp_id="+empId;
     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "otherfile.php",
       data: data ,
       success: function(){         
          alert("Employee deleted successfully.");
       }
     });
  }
}
```

In delete.php you can take the employee id by using `$_POST['emp_id']`

Comment: In controller file have some more function so how to call the exact delete function through ajax. i dnt have experience in ajax. thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily by using jquery

```
var dataString = 'any_variable='+ <?=$phpvariable?>;        
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "otherfile.php",
data: dataString,
success: function(msg){         
    // msg is return value of your otherfile.php
}
}); //END $.ajax
```

Comment: hi actually this is my question i call deleteRole function with parameter foreach but i dnt know how to receive parameter value in JS function.... please understand correctly

Comment: in otherfile.php receive any_variable variable. use $myvariable = $_POST['any_variable']; to receive

Answer (score 0):

I would add an extra variable in to the delete link address. Preferrably the ID of the row that you need to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Concrete-5 CMS. But, i am giving you the general idea
I think, you are using some button on which users can click if they want to delete role.

`<td>".$ih->button_js(t('Delete'), "deleteRole('".$data['role_id']."')", 'left', 'error')."</td>`

My suggestion,
add `onClick` to button
`onClick="deleteEmployee(roleId);"` // roleId - dynamic id of the role by looping over

Frankly speaking dude, i dont know how you will add this to your button that i guess there would surely be some way to simply add this to existing html.

And now, simply use Sajith's function

```
// Sajith's function here
function deleteEmployee(empId){

    var confirm=confirm("Do you want to delete?");
    if (confirm){
        var url = "path/to/delete.php";
        var data = "emp_id="+empId;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "otherfile.php",
            data: data ,
            success: function(){         
                alert("Employee deleted successfully.");
            }
        });
    }
}
```